# i want ui:inputradio label to display to the right of the radio currently it is to the left followed by radio?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, ui, radio-button

I want the radio button first and the label to the right of the radio button

here is my code

```
<tr>
    <td width="150px" class="uiLabel-right form-element__label uiLabel">
        <ui:inputradio name="DistListSelectId" text="{!v.distributionListOptions.name}"
                       value="{!selRecs.isListSelected}" label="{!selRecs.displayName}" change="{!c.captureValue}" /></td>
    
    <td>                                                                
       <!-- <ui:outputText value="{!selRecs.displayName}" aura:id="radioResult"/>--></td>
    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ui:inputRadio` has been deprecated since May 1st, 2021, and should not be used. Instead, use [`lightning:radioGroup`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example), which has the radio options to the left of the labels by default. Otherwise, if you want more control over the UI, just use a plain [radio input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

```
<input type="radio" id="someId" name="DistListSelectId" 
  checked="{!selRecs.isListSelected}" onchange="{!c.captureValue}" />
<label for="someId">
  {!selRecs.displayName}
</label>
```